# Visual Studio - Can I open aspx and code file with one action?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, editor

Right now, I don't have the "Show All Files" option selected - that means I only see the .aspx files in my web application project, and don't see the .vb or .designer.vb files.

I can open the code by right-clicking on the aspx, and selecting "View Code", but it would be really nice if there was a way to double-click on the aspx file and have it open both the aspx and the aspx.vb.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

- F7 will show the code behind when you're in the design view
- Shift + F7 will show the design view when you're in code behind

thats the fastest way to switch and I think the best way to achieve your goal of switching between files.

if you mean you want a split screen that isn't possible - at least without extensions

---

**Edit:** I just discovered that you can single click (or otherwise select via the keyboard) on the item itself in the solution explorer and hit either F7 or Shift+F7 there to directly open the code or designer directly. No double click needed. Never realized that before ;-)

Comment: I find that I'm usually opening both at the same time - I didn't know about F7, which is quicker than right-clicking, view code.  Don't care about getting a split screen.

Comment: And on my copy of VS2008, F7 toggles between code and aspx - Shift-F7 doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @chris - in C# in older versions (I think VS2005 and earlier) F7 used to have that behavior and then they changed it. so it sounds like its still the old way for VB.NET